# Realm Xamarin: The type or namespace name 'IList<>' could not be found

Tags: xamarin, realm

public IList coordinates { get; }

Error "The type or namespace name 'IList<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (TouristiKo.Droid)"

Comment: We have to less informations to help you. Have you tried to use something like RealmList? IList is implemented in "using System.Collections;"

Answer (score 1):

Specify the type of the list

```
public IList<PointOrWhatever> coordinates { get; }
```

Comment: Also, make sure to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` in your using statements.